# Public variable can't be set by subscribe

Tags: angular, ionic4, angular7

It's a Angular(7) project with Ionic 4 framework., with TypeScript.
We need to get the ''userIdservice'' variable with the API call from the service (user.service.ts)

So when the subscribe excute the response they can't set the 'userIdservice' value. They still 'undefined' when I need to call the 'this.userSevice.'userIdservice'.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { ApiService } from './api.service';
    import { CommonService } from './common.service';
    import { HttpClient, HttpParams, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class UserService {

    public userIdservice:string;

    httpOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Content-Type':  'application/json'
      })
    };
    
    createUser(email, nome, password){
       this.http.post(this.api.url + '/users.json?access_token=' + xToken, 
        dataUser , this.httpOptions).subscribe(function(response: any){
       this.userIdservice = response.data.user.id;
       console.log("User id",  this.userIdservice); // Here in console i can see the ID
      },
      err => {console.log("Error"); },
      () => { ... another things... }
      );
    }
  }
```

What I need to do to get the 'userIdservice' with the response API value from all my APP components ?

Comment: Consider moving your request  code to a service to handle executing calls.  Then set the return value of those calls to a public variable in your service.  This will make the value publicly available to all consumers of that service.

Comment: What is the data of response object returned from service?

Comment: @HojatAfsharan The data get from response is the number of the 'User ID', i get when I make a console.log. But in the outside I get 'undefided'.

Comment: How is your service provided? You probably need to post more code including the entire service and module code so someone can give you an answer.

Comment: @HopeyOne my code below is the resume part of the service (user.service.ts), let me edit that to improve.

Answer (score 2):

**The mistake**

You are implementing the callback function as `function(){this.userIdservice ='a'}`. Using this syntax you will lose your reference to this.

**The solution**

Using an arrow function instead `() => { this.userIdservice ='a'}` will retain the reference to this.

**In your code**

```
createUser(email, nome, password){
   this.http.post(this.api.url + '/users.json?access_token=' + xToken, 
    dataUser , this.httpOptions).subscribe((response: any) => {
   this.userIdservice = response.data.user.id;
   console.log("User id",  this.userIdservice); // Should work now
  },
  err => {console.log("Error"); },
  () => { ... another things... }
  );
}
```